# Randomize control visibility (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, random

I have been searching for a solution to this but haven't come across one yet and i'm not too good at randomizing with c#.

I have three asp.net controls and I would like to make visible one of those controls at any one time.

The controls may be like this

panel 1

panel 2

panel 3

So I guess all of these controls would be set to visible='false' by default. Then the randomize method would choose one of those controls and make it visible='true'.

I think the hardest part here would be to put the controls into an array to randomize? Again, i'm not sure how to do that so any help would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var visiblePanel = rnd.Next(1, 4);
switch (visiblePanel) {
    case 1:
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 2:
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        break;
    case 3:
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

Comment: This code is what I was looking for. I was only looking for quick fix though but moreover I need to learn more about randomization as it is a weak point in my coding knowledge. Thank you for the code and your help Tim.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Panel[] array1 = new Panel[3];
array1[0] = panel1;
array1[1] = panel2;
array1[2] = panel3;

foreach(Panel p in array1) {
  p.Visible = False;
}

Random rand = new Random();
int toshow = rand.next(0, 3);
array1[toshow].Visible = true;
```

This was conveiced from my head without any IDE to support if it works correctly. The Class name for `random` might be wrong (isn't it in the Math Namespace?)

Comment: Some day all panels are visible ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I heard that you need to do rand.next(0, highest+1). I once tried and I think I couldn't make it go up to the highest number... Also I don't think so; it would go EXCEPTION: ARRAY INDEX OUT OF RANGE :D

Comment: what i wanted to say is, you are only making panels visible and not invisible.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In his question there's a sentence: "So I guess all of these controls would be set to visible='false' by default.". So they're invisible by default... I approached it from this angle.

Comment: He mentioned: "I would like to make visible one of those controls at any one time." Your answer would make all panels visible sometime.

Comment: Thank you for your effort sinni and Thank you Tim for clearing that up.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't really get why... Sorry. I think that usually all panels would be invisible, so I choose ONE of the panels by random, and make it visible. What is the problem, actually? Is it the lifecycle of an ASP.NET page? Then put a "if is post back" contrcut.

Comment: @sinni: your code is ok, but i'm only missing a loop over all panels that makes only that one visible that has the index `toshow` in your array. The other should be invisible when they were visible before. They might be invisible by default, but if your code could be triggered more than once, the panel that was recently visible should be invisible. Never mind, the OP is satisfied ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter ahh, if my code gets triggered more than once then it will make more than one visible, I know that. But I didn't figure it would be a problem. Alright then